# Julia: running code blocks in Juno / Atom

Tags: julia, atom-editor, code-formatting, juno-ide

Whenever I try to 'run block' to run a block of Julia code in Atom, it just runs the currently selected line. I don't understand what's wrong. I've tried all the different delimiters ('##', '# %%', and '# --') and it still isn't recognizing code blocks. The formatting itself also suggests it's not recognizing the block delimiters.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to say without some more info - what versions of Atom, the relevant Atom packages, and the Julia packages are you on? Also this is maybe one of the rare questions that would benefit from a screenshot :)

Comment: i ended up getting really frustrated and doing a fresh reinstall of Atom, Juno, and Julia altogether. After I did this, the code formatting works as expected. There must have been some incompatibility in my version of Atom and the relevant code formatting packages for Juno...

Comment: Atom does no run code. You need to at least specify the third-party package you're using to run code.

Comment: I specified it - Juno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reinstalled Juno/Atom/Julia fresh and everything worked out.

Answer (score 1):

The block delimiter is `##` with a space after the second octothorpe. Try, for example, `## ---`